# What is the difference in between "so as to ~" and "in order to ~"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I know that both "in order to Verb" phrase and "so as to Verb" phrase describe the purpose of doing something.

But, I would like to know if there are any differences between them.

For example, the below two sentences might be examined about it.

> **Sentence A**: "We went early so as to get good seats."
>
> **Sentence B**: "We went early in order to get good seats."

Comment: When you enter a new question, a list of suggested previous questions appears below the title field. Always be sure to read them to see if your question has already been asked.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Sorry, next time, I will do check it out! Thank you.

Comment: If, after reading the duplicate, you still don't understand the answer, of course, please ask a different question about _exactly_ what isn't clear.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Okay, I will do so. Thank you for the kindness! Have a lovely night.